# JNA. Создание структуры из указателя

Tags: java, winapi, jna

Добрый день, коллеги!
Возникла необходимость плотно поработать с WinApi из Java. JNI не хочу использовать из-за лени переключаться между средами, компиляторами и т.д. - решил применить широкоизвестный фреймворк JNA. Суть проблемы в следующем:

Имеется замечательная функция [GetIfTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365943(v=vs.85).aspx) которая имеет следующую сигнатуру:

```
DWORD GetIfTable(
  _Out_   PMIB_IFTABLE pIfTable,
  _Inout_ PULONG       pdwSize,
  _In_    BOOL         bOrder
);
```

Как видно она работает со структурой [MIB_IFTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366842(v=vs.85).aspx) имеющей следующий вид:

```
typedef struct _MIB_IFTABLE {
  DWORD     dwNumEntries;
  MIB_IFROW table[ANY_SIZE];
} MIB_IFTABLE, *PMIB_IFTABLE;
```

Если почитать MSDN про данную функцию, то можно увидеть интересный способ ее применения:

1. Передаем в функцию созданную по умолчанию структуру и ее размер (либо `null` и `dwSize = 0`) в ответ, функция вернет нам ошибку буфера и запишет в dwSize количество байт памяти которые необходимо выделить для хранения выходного результата.
2. Выделяем память и повторно вызываем метод. Он возвращает 0 - все ок. Берем полученный массив структур и работаем по нему.

Применительно к Java и JNA в данном случае возникает проблема - невозможно объявить в структуре массив неизвестной длинны, а значит придется работать с указателями (P.S> сразу оговорюсь если работать не с указателями, а с инстансами структур, указав например массив `table` равным 1000 элементам, то все отработает более менее корректно).

Объявляем структуры и функции:

```
class MIB_IFTABLE extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends MIB_IFTABLE implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public static class ByValue extends MIB_IFTABLE implements Structure.ByValue { }

        public WinDef.DWORD dwNumEntries = new WinDef.DWORD();   //Количество интерфейсов в массиве
        public Pointer table = Pointer.NULL;


        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"dwNumEntries", "table"});
        }

        public MIB_IFTABLE() {
        }

        public MIB_IFTABLE(Pointer p) {
            super(p);
        }
    }

    int GetIfTable(Pointer pIfTable, ULONGByReference pwdSize, WinDef.BOOL bOrder);
```

Ну и пробуем со всем этим поработать:

```
Pointer pIfTable = Pointer.NULL;
WinApiHelper helper = WinApiHelper.INSTANCE;

WinDef.ULONGByReference dwSize = new WinDef.ULONGByReference(new WinDef.ULONG(0));
int res = helper.GetIfTable(pIfTable, dwSize, new WinDef.BOOL(false));
pIfTable = new Memory(dwSize.getValue().longValue());
res = helper.GetIfTable(pIfTable, dwSize, new WinDef.BOOL(false));

WinApiHelper.MIB_IFTABLE table = new WinApiHelper.MIB_IFTABLE(pIfTable);
```

И вот тут-то наступает нежданчик - данные в `table`отсутствуют! Т.е. структура не создалась и незаполнилась по переданному ей указателю. Причем если посмотреть на данные по указателю pIfTable - то они там очень даже есть, но вот добраться до них нормально я не могу. Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После создания структуры по указателя надо было выполнить метод `read()`.

Comment: Единственный момент который мне интересен - а как он будет разруливать проблемы c выравниванием.